# PHP Backtrack_Limit_Error on preg_replace when matching nothing

Tags: php, regex

Converting a possibly nested HTML `UL` to CSV (4 fields) using PHP preg_replace I run onto a snag. The following line takes care of part of nested lists which go unchanged (except for removed newlines) into one of the fields created from the topmost UL:

```
$idx_string = preg_replace("|(<li>.*?)\n+(<ul>)\n+(.*?</li></ul></li>)|si","$1$2$3", $idx_string);
```

Now on some large lists *without* nested lists (checked there's no such thing as `<ul>` in it at this point of conversion) this fails due to backtrack_limit_error. So while I know how to get over it, I can't figure how matching nothing could trigger the backtrack limit at all.  According to what I've found, preg_replace returns either the new string or the unchanged old string (besides NULL/FALSE on error). So how does backtrack get in here?

The list items look like this:

```
<li><a href="9848.php">Algeria - Italy.</a></li>

<li>Go sailing<br>
<a href="11434.php">Anglesey / Wight / Guernsey / Jersey</a></li>

<li><a href="11367.php">d'Anjou et du Saumurois, Carte des Gouvernements</a><br>
Check out the old places!</li>
```

The CSV looks like this:

```
|9848.php|Algeria - Italy.|
Go sailing|11434.php|Anglesey - Anglesey / Wight / Guernsey / Jersey|
|11367.php|d'Anjou et du Saumurois, Carte des Gouvernements|Check out the old places!
```

So in effect all tags are stripped and the remainder split into 4 fields. The odd nested list is stuffed into the third field as is, that is with `<ul>` & `<li>` tags, only newlines stripped.

This is some old PHP 4 code utilized as fallback mechanism. `DOMDocument` might be the better general approach, but I don't want to invest much time in this and the format of the list is pretty strict & simple.

**Summing up**

Looking at the code again with Jerry's comments in mind it becomes obvious how the first group `(<li>.*?)` has PHP starting at the first `<li>` right at the top of the file and chewing the whole file in search for a `<ul>`, all into one backtrack space.

Enclosing the statement in `if (stripos($idx_string, '<ul')) { ... }` block reduces the chance of triggering the error, as does raising pcre.backtrack_limit to 1000000, which is the default as of PHP 5.3.7 anyway, but was not updated to here for one reason or another. So much wrapping up for the record.

Comment: Parsing HTML with regular expression is a not recommended, use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: Could you include some sample lines?

Comment: @Jerry Did so. However, the problem is not the list (that is parsed fine), but how/why a preg-replace matching nothing can trigger backtrack_error.

Comment: @Sniffer I know that and I think I mentioned it. With the odd nested list DOM parsing would hardly get easier.

Comment: @JayAitch Hmm, yea, there's no match in that sample with your current regex. The thing with regex is that it will try to get a match wherever possible, and even if that means it has to test thousands of different combinations, and this arises when you have a lot of `*` and/or `+` (lazy or not, it doesn't matter). And when you have a really large file... well, that's where the chance of exhausting the backtrack limit increases.

Comment: @Jerry So the backtrack happens on the left side of the statement? My understanding was it came into effect rather on the right side when a large parenthized match has occured and is reused per $n. Sorry for the somewhat clumsy 'left' & 'right' side, of course the 'right' side depends on the left, so this always is part of the game.

Comment: @JayAitch Well, strictly speaking, the 'right' side backtracks the most usually. One could say that there's 100 backtrack (depending on the size of file and on how much it already backtracked; this number increases the more there's backtracking) for each 1 backtrack on the left side.

Comment: @Jerry Thanks for clearing the fog overhere. For the time being I could get over the error by raising backtrack_limit_error to 1000000, but now I understand what is going on.